# Get vector values in java

Tags: java, vector

I'm new in java
I got a vector like this:

```
    InputStream inputStream;
    String string;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add(inputstream);
    vector.add(string);
    vector(fileoutputstream);
```

The problem is they convert to object
How can i get all of them like this:

```
    InputStream inputStream2;
    String string2;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2;
    inputStream2 = vector.get(0);
    string2 = vector.get(1);
    fileOutputStream2 = vector.get(2);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector is a generic class. But I have to ask, why are you adding an InputStream, String, and an OutputStream object in a single vector class?

But if you must do something like this, then you should initialise your class as follows:

```
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
InputStream inputStream2 = (InputStream) vector.get(0);
String string2 = (String) vector.get(1);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2 = (FileOutputStream) vector.get(2);
```